# gazebo-ros-pkgs for ros-Indigo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When will gazebo-ros-pkgs for ros-Indigo be ready. I tried downloading the source but the default  hw sim does not compile.  Any ideas when this will be resolved? ( binaries be supported)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6373/gazebo-ros-pkgs-for-ros-indigo/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/449/rnunziata/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 107 on 2014-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can follow progress in this [issue](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/206).

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodríguez T](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26/adolfo-rodr%C3%ADguez-t/) with karma: 275 on 2014-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1